Access Database not working in docker with windows enviroment
Run in docker with using installer for
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 AS build
SHELL ["powershell"]

### 32 Bit Access
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/C/35C84C36-661A-44E6-9324-8786B8DBE231/accessdatabaseengine.exe "C:/setup/AccessDatabaseEngine.exe"
RUN start-process -Filepath "C:/setup/AccessDatabaseEngine.exe" -ArgumentList @('/quiet') -Wait;  \
    Remove-Item -Force "C:/setup/AccessDatabaseEngine.exe"

## 64 Bit Access
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/C/35C84C36-661A-44E6-9324-8786B8DBE231/accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe "C:/setup/AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe"
RUN start-process -Filepath "C:/setup/AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe" -ArgumentList @('/quiet') -Wait;  \
    Remove-Item -Force "C:/setup/AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe"

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

# Start IIS Remote Management and monitor IIS
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe", "w3svc"];

EXPOSE 80

When run the code con.open and face the dead without any exception.
 //2.  Establish a connection to the database and execute the insert commands
try { 
 var con = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=newfile.mdb");
 con.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
     {                    
         throw ex;
     }

 //3. write one row
 var createTableScript = "INSERT INTO testTable(name, code, remarks) VALUES ('testing name', 1234, 'test remark');";

 // Create a command and execute it
 using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(createTableScript, con))
 {
     try
     {
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {                    
         throw ex;
     }
 }

Problem start after microsoft change the new installer link for the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable.
The con.open() make the application 'dead' and not catching any exception
.
What i have tried as below

change the Provider from Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 also not working with dead at con.Open() and no error message

Use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 same as above.

remove the /quiet after download and install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable and no error show. For both 32 bit or 64 bit.

use Provider from Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and show that not register in the server.

tried with aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019.

check with the mdb file do not have access district.



What you're doing is doubly unsupported. Running 32- and 64-bit versions of the Access database engine simultaneously is unsupported (see the error messages if you don't use /quiet), and using the Access database engine server-side is unsupported (see the Not intended section under https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

I had try remove the /quiet no error show. and install successfully.

What i have tried as below
change the Provider from Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 also not working with dead at con.Open() and no error message
Use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 same as above.
remove the /quiet after download and install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable and no error show. For both 32 bit or 64 bit.
use Provider from Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and show that not register in the server.
tried with aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019.
check with the mdb file do not have access district.

"and face the dead without any exception." - you aren't getting any exception details because your code doesn't show any attempt at logging any exceptions, and your catch block incorrectly re-throws it.

tried and add back the catch and same without any catch.
